# Removing everything between 2 strings with Google sheets RE2

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I'm trying to remove something from a product title as part of a Google sheet

- Example Johner Gladstone Pinot Noir 2015, 75CL
- Stella Artois Premium Lager Bottle, 1 X 660 Ml
- Pepesza Ppsh-40 Vodka Tommy Gun, 1 L

And I want to be able to remove everything from the `,`  and either the `CL`, `ML` or `L`.

The problem I'm running into is that I don't know enough about regex and I'm struggling to find a good place to learn!

What I've tried so far is below

- `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[, ]\QML|CL\E","")`

  but this doesn't work and I think its because `[, ]` isn't a valid part.
- `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\*\QML|CL\E","")`

  because I know that `,` is the only punctuation in the titles - I've also tried this but not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to get is

```golang
(?i), .*?[CM]?L
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RG8nut/1/). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `, .*?` - comma, space, and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (due to `*?`, if you need as many as possible use `*` instead)
- `[CM]?L` - `C` or `M` (optionally due to `?`) and then an `L` char.

However, you can simply match from a `,` + space till the end of the line:

```golang
", .*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RG8nut/2). Here, the first comma+space is matched and then the rest of the string (line, since `.` does not match line breaks by default).

See [the regular expression syntax accepted by RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).